# Using multiple configs in the same group to interpolate values in a yaml file

Tags: fb-hydra, omegaconf

In Hydra I have the following configuration:

```
├── conf
    │   ├── config.yaml
    │   ├── callbacks
    │   │   ├── callback_01.yaml
    │   │   └── callback_02.yaml
    │   └── trainer
    │       ├── default.yaml
```

The callbacks have a structure like this:

```
_target_: callback_to_instantiate
```

I need to pass to the trainer/default.yaml both the callbacks through interpolation.
I tried like this:

```
    _target_: pytorch_lightning.Trainer
    callbacks:
        - ${callbacks.callback_01}
        - ${callbacks.callback_02}
```

With the config.yaml like this:

```
    defaults:
      - _self_
      - trainer: default
```

I did also other trials but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to interpolate like that in a yaml file by using two or more yaml files that are in the config group?
I would like if possible to keep this structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the recommended approach is:

1. compose a mapping whose values are the desired callbacks, and then
2. use the [`oc.dict.values`](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1_branch/custom_resolvers.html#oc-dict-keys-value) OmegaConf resolver to get a list of values from that dictionary.

```yaml
# conf/config.yaml
defaults:
  - callbacks@_callback_dict.cb1: callback_01
  - callbacks@_callback_dict.cb2: callback_02
  - trainer: default
  - _self_
```

```yaml
# conf/trainer/default.yaml
_target_: pytorch_lightning.Trainer
callbacks: ${oc.dict.values:_callback_dict}
```

```py
# my_app.py
from typing import Any
import hydra
from omegaconf import DictConfig, OmegaConf

@hydra.main(config_path="conf", config_name="config")
def app(cfg: DictConfig) -> Any:
    OmegaConf.resolve(cfg)
    del cfg._callback_dict
    print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()
```

At the command line:

```
$ python my_app.py
trainer:
  _target_: pytorch_lightning.Trainer
  callbacks:
  - _target_: callback_to_instantiate_01
  - _target_: callback_to_instantiate_02
```

For reference, there is [an open issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/1939) on Hydra's github repo advocating for an improved user experience around